# Только часть объекта в input для useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать useEffect зависящим только от части объекта?

В props компонента передается массив объектов, а useEffect должен обновляться только тогда, когда изменилось определенное свойства объекта этого массива.

Пример ниже работает, но вряд ли подход с сериализацией является правильным.

```
({arrayOfData}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('updated');
  }, [
    // Сериализация данных
    arrayOfData.map((d) => d.someKey).join()
  ]);
  // ...
};
```

Правильным было бы разбить данные, но что если это невозможно? Как быть в таким ситуациях?

Comment: В вашем случае не стоит использовать вариант с массивом зависимостей. Испольуйте вариант без него (не путать с пустым массивом), а всю логику поместите в самом коде хука.

Comment: @Spatz, тогда придется хранить предыдущие значения для сравнения их в теле эффекта?

Comment: да, обычно это делают используя useRef

Comment: @Spatz, такой вариант тоже рассматривал, но хочется найти более изящный подход)